# How do you interact (close, minimize, maximize windows) with Files Windows in Ubuntu 22.10?

Tags: nautilus, wmctrl, gtk4

In Ubuntu 22.04, you could use wmctrl to interact with Files windows. In Ubuntu 22.10, wmctrl no longer works. How can one interact with Files windows in Ubuntu 22.10?

Ubuntu 22.04

```
userabc@apollo:~$ wmctrl -lp
0x05000008  0 44604  apollo Downloads          <= I have my Downloads directory opened
```

Ubuntu 22.10

```
userabc@apollo:~$ wmctrl -lp
                    <= I have my Downloads directory opened but is not listed with wmctrl
```

From the Ubuntu 22.10 release notes it states, "The default file manager Nautilus has switched to GTK4." This would explain why wmctrl no longer lists opened Files windows.